# What does "all of six months" mean?

Tags: meaning

> —[Source](https://twitter.com/emptynetters/status/172380288305991680)
>
> A: What are your memories of the U. S. - Soviet Union game in 1980, Seth? ;-)
>
> B: I was **all of six months old** that day. ;)

Does he mean he's exactly six months old that day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When used with age, the *all of* means that someone is or was too young for something or doing something.

> [all of](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/all) - *As much as (often used ironically of an amount or quantity considered small by the speaker)*

This means, he was too young to have memories.

Comment: This can be more generally used when you want to say that you don't have much of something in a slightly jokey way. "I can't come out to the cinema, I have all of £10 left in my account!"